# Merge r brings error "'by' must specify uniquely valid columns"

Tags: r, merge

R doesn't like me today...

I have two tables asembled via cbind(). Tab 1 (**dwd_nogap**) is

```
  x1                 col1_x1       col2_x1      
A "1982 12 01 00:00" "        0.4" "          0"
B "1982 12 02 00:00" "       -0.5" "          0"
C "1982 12 03 00:00" "       -0.2" "          0"
D "1982 12 04 00:00" "         -1" "        0.1"
E "1982 12 05 00:00" "       -0.9" "          0"
F "1982 12 06 00:00" "        3.7" "        4.1"
```

Tab 2 (**dwd_gap**) is:

```
     x2                 col1_x2       col2_x2      
[1,] "1982 12 01 00:00" "        0.4" "          0"
[2,] "1982 12 03 00:00" "       -0.2" "          0"
[3,] "1982 12 04 00:00" "         -1" "        0.1"
[4,] "1982 12 05 00:00" "       -0.9" "          0"
[5,] "1982 12 06 00:00" "        3.7" "        4.1"
[6,] "1982 12 07 00:00" "          7" "        5.8"
```

My merge command is:

```
exporttab <- merge(x=dwd_nogap,y=dwd_gap,by.x=dwd_nogap[,1],by.y=dwd_gap[,1], fill=-9999)
```

In my opinion the command is correct, but it's apparently not doing well...

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns
```

Comment: Did you actually study the examples of `?merge`?. You need to specify the actual column names such as `by.x= "x1", ,by.y= "x2"`

Comment: My error was even more trivial, I forgot to place the ''. I tried the actual column names but with x1 instead of 'x1'.

Comment: I didn't know that `merge` supports `fill`. That was a nice bonus. It's not even mentioned in `?merge`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rather give names of the column on which you want to merge:

```
exporttab <- merge(x=dwd_nogap, y=dwd_gap, by.x='x1', by.y='x2', fill=-9999)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I tried for a right outer join [as per my requirement]:

```
m1 <- merge(x=companies, y=rounds2, by.x=companies$permalink, 
            by.y=rounds2$company_permalink, all.y=TRUE)
# Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns
m1 <- merge(x=companies, y=rounds2, by.x=c("permalink"), 
            by.y=c("company_permalink"), all.y=TRUE)
```

This worked.